# UI Text Field Design

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, sketch-3

So, I was trying to mimic a video that uses sketch to design a login screen I really like. I had a question about how I can make a text field in Xcode look like the one that is being designed in the video.

Here is the video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gA_hFHkhqFM&t=87s

Here is a picture of the text field I want to design:

[image: Text Field Image I want to deisgn]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to do it in the storyboard

Find/Create a blurry image and set it as an image view's image. Fill the view with the image view and add constraints. Add a new text field on top of the image view. Set these things:

- border style to none

[image]

- Text color to white

[image]

- Background color to a black color with an alpha value and tint color to white as well.

[image]

This can be set by using the RGB slider in the color picker. Use the slider at the very bottom to adjust the alpha:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to add a UIView with a black background. Set its alpha to 0.7.

Then add a UITextField on top. Set its border style to none, then the background color to clear.

You're done!

Comment: you mean UITextField background still dark ?

Comment: I did everything you guys said but for some reason adding a clear text field on top of it doesnt change anything